# setBackgroundResource() iphone monotouch equivalent

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Is there  an equivalent of R.drawable. on monotouch?
I'm also  searching for a way to set an xml graphic resource definition as background of a UIView or subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a different world here.  iOS does not have an equivalent of what you're using on Android.

General practice is to use a static class in MonoTouch:

```
public static class Resources
{
   public static readonly UIImage Background = UIImage.FromFile("Background.png");
}
```

And use this anywhere you need it from C# code.  If you set an image in a XIB file, it will use `UIImage.FromBundle()`, which caches the image across views.  `UIImage.FromFile()` is generally better when using it from a static class, however.

See more on UIImage loading and MonoTouch here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Images?highlight=images  (near bottom)

Comment: As i know, maybe i implement some basic vector to pass as raster for generating all backgrounds used or simple export some new graphic as png...